# How to use a field value instead of pk in the url?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I want to show the username or name of the person I want to update details for, in the url of update view. The only method I know is to display pk in the url. Is there a method to replace pk with a field value? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `slug` for this.You can install slug using `pip install django-autoslug` For example:

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField
class A(models.Model):
     field = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     slug = AutoSlugField(unique_with='id', populate_from='field')
```

In `urls.py` use slug like this:

```
path('<slug>/..../', views...., name='....'),
```

Comment: Reverse for 'centreupdate' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 2}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['NewApp/centreupdate\\/(?P<slug>[^/]+)\\/$']. I am getting this error today. I did exactly what you told.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can simply define a `slug` or `str` part in the url. For example:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<str:username>/', views.user_details),
]
```

and in your view, you can for example query with the `username` field is the `username` URL parameter:

```
# app/views.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def user_details(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    # ...
```